# changes material-ui checkbox state checked, unchecked or indeterminated based on other checkbox click, without using state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

i am using material-ui checkbox, i need to change checkbox state programmatically checked, unchecked or indererminate based on other checkbox clicked. there can be a list of checkboxes what i need to change, and i do not want to use state in react.

```
import React from 'react'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

export default class CheckboxesTest extends React.Component {
    onChange = (e) => {
        let cbs = document.getElementById("checkboxId").querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for (let i = 0; i > cbs.length; i++)
            cbs[0].checked = true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Checkbox
                    defaultChecked
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <div id="checkboxId">
                    <Checkbox />
                    <Checkbox />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

when i used browser default checkbox then it works,

```
import React from 'react'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

export default class CheckboxesTest extends React.Component {
    onChange = (event) => {
        let elem = document.getElementById("checkboxId").querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            elem[i].indeterminate = false
            elem[i].checked = event.target.checked;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Checkbox
                    defaultChecked
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <div id="checkboxId">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use state, but your code isn't working properly because the [SwitchBase](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/internal/SwitchBase.js) component isn't aware of a change in the internal checkbox component.

The native checkbox element is being updated internally based on the checked attribute. But by just setting the checked property, there will be no change event emitted.

You will have to dispatch a [change event manually](https://hustle.bizongo.in/simulate-react-on-change-on-controlled-components-baa336920e04), but this needs you to override some React logic to make it work which I do not recommend.

Another possible solution would to be to wrap the checkbox in a component which holds the state of a single checkbox. By defining a `setChecked` method on the class component, you can call this method to change the checked state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-u822z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: thanks for commenting and suggestions, i do not want state, because, the number of checkbox is dynamic and it can be more depth, like when i click one checkbox , it changes all the checkboxes in inner depth. each checkbox can be a parent of multiple child checkbox or parent checkbox.

Comment: Ok, that shouldn't be a problem and can be solved with just a single state property. If each checkbox has a unique identifier you can actually make a tree dictionary like so:  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-phf31?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

you can use intermediate custom component get expected solution.

Main component be like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import CheckboxIndependant from "./component/CheckboxIndependant";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {

  onChange = e => {
    let elem = document
      .getElementById("checkboxId")
      .querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      elem[i].checked = !event.target.checked;
      elem[i].click()
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox onChange={this.onChange} />
        <hr />
        <div id="checkboxId">
          <CheckboxIndependant />
          <CheckboxIndependant />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Definition of `CheckboxIndependant` is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

class CheckboxIndependant extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      checked: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  render() {
    const newProps = Object.assign(
      {
        onChange: this.handleInputChange,
        checked: this.state.checked
      },
      this.props
    );
    return <Checkbox {...newProps} />;
  }
}

export default CheckboxIndependant;
```

Example Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vuqlsa

Comment: hi, @Sachink, thanks for your commenting, how it works with indeterminate? like, if i select all and then deselect one of child 2 checkboxes. i want parent will be checked, unchecked and indeterminate.